# Using TimeSpan format for Azure Database using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

Im trying to insert data from my ASP.NET MVC application using Entity Framework into my Azure Database.

On my Database, I have a column called ShutdownTime with the datatype Time.
After implementing the Table into my ASP.NET MVC application, I can see, by inserting data to my table, I have to use the TimeSpan datatype.

```
public partial class Vm
{
    public int Vm_Id { get; set; }
    public System.TimeSpan ShutdownTime { get; set; }
    public string VmName { get; set; }
    public string DeploymentId { get; set; }
}
```

This is my function

```
public ActionResult Edit(string newVmName, TimeSpan newShutdownTime, string newServiceName, bool startVm)
{
    var NewVmEntry = new Vm();
    newShutdownTime = new TimeSpan(1, 12, 20, 10);

    // Assign standard name
    NewVmEntry.VmName = "MyVM";
    NewVmEntry.ShutdownTime = newShutdownTime;
    NewVmEntry.DeploymentId = "MyDID";

    azureContext.Vms.Add(NewVmEntry);
    azureContext.SaveChanges();

    if (startVm == true)
    {
        StartVM(newServiceName, newVmName);
    }
    return View("Index");
}
```

But I always get this error at `SaveChanges()`

*"SqlDbType.Time overflow.  Value '1.12:20:10' is out of range.  Must be between 00:00:00.0000000 and 23:59:59.9999999."*

The error seems to be pretty clear. But can I solve the issue?

Comment: If it is shutdown time why are you using timespan? Use DateTime object instead.

Comment: TimeSpan was automatically generated by entity framework. In my Table I'm just using Time

Comment: Are you sure `TimeSpan` is the correct type? The DB Time field is a time of day (e.g. 9:30 AM) not a time span (e.g. 15 minutes).

Comment: @Ben Robinson EF does not allow dateTime. For Time in DB it generates Timespan

Comment: @user2877820 Why are you giving 1 day while creating timespan in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time(7) only supports timespan of less than 24 hours. Read this post:

[Entity Framework TimeSpan - Time Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15567178/entity-framework-timespan-time-error)

Try to remove the day part from your timespan.

```
newShutdownTime = TimeSpan(12, 20,10);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I think storing a time of day in a timespan is that good an idea but the error is pretty clear.

```
newShutdownTime = new TimeSpan(1, 12, 20, 10);
```

In the above line you are creating a timespan of duration 1 day, 12 hrs, 20 minutes and 10 seconds. Obviously this will not work because the only way a timespan makes sense as a time of day is if it represents the amount of time after midnight. It is not clear what time of day you want to set this va;lue to but the below will not fail in the same way

```
newShutdownTime = new TimeSpan(0, 12, 20, 10);
```

this will set the field to 12 hrs, 20 minutes and 10 seconds, or in time of day terms 12:20:10.